# the @ModelAttribute annotation is omitted, why i can get the bean in jsp view, this a default

Tags: java, spring, annotations

the @ModelAttribute annotation is omitted,but also can get in jsp.

i cann't find any correctly

```java
@RequestMapping("/problemViewList")
    public ModelAndView ProblemViewList(Address address) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("from");
    }
```

i want to know what happen under the air

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that @ModelAttribute will add as default if the parameter type is not primitive type.  but i cann't find this in spring doc, this is bug?

Answer (score 0):

i got this when reading source code.

if no annotation in parameter, the method resolveHandlerArguments in HandlerMethodInvoker will add annotation by this para Type.
not primitive --> @ModelAttribute